# Determining whether a transformation is linear based on input and output coordinates

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I was asked to check if there is a linear transformation that lives up to the requirements. If so, I should come up with T(x,y,x). Otherwise, I should explain why not.

a) $T:R^3 \to R^2$, so that $T(0,2,-1)=(-1,3)$, $T(2,-2,-1)=(1,4)$ and $T(1,-4,1)=(2,1)$.

b) $T:R^3 \to R^2$, so that $T(1,1,-1)=(-1,3)$, $T(1,1,1)=(1,4)$ and $T(1,0,1)=(2,1)$.

The way I resolved it was as follows:
a) I created the following matrices:
$$\begin{matrix}a&b&c\\d&e&f\end{matrix}$$

multiplied by

$$\begin{matrix}0&2&1\\2&-2&4\\-1&-1&1\end{matrix}$$

equals

$$\begin{matrix}-1&1&2\\3&4&1\end{matrix}$$

Then I wrote down the resulting two sets of equations. First:

2b-c=-1

2a-2b-c=1

a-4b+c=2

and resolved this through a matrix.

Next:

2e-f=3

2d-2e-f=4

d-4e+1f=1

and tried to resolve this via a matrix, but there was a contradiction, so no solutions. I assumed that meant that the transformation is not linear.

I did exactly the same for b), but this time the resulting two systems of equations both came out with one solution each. I assumed that this means this is indeed a linear transformation.

Is the reasoning correct?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the transformation in the first case is also linear. To find the matrix we just have to set up the linear system of equations
$$
\begin{bmatrix}a&b&c\\d&e&f\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}0&2&1\\2&-2&4\\-1&-1&1\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}-1&1&2\\3&4&1\end{bmatrix}.
$$
The square matrix of the system is invertible, hence, the solution is
$$
\begin{bmatrix}a&b&c\\d&e&f\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}-1&1&2\\3&4&1\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}0&2&1\\2&-2&4\\-1&-1&1\end{bmatrix}^{-1}
$$
Similar system can be solved in the second case.

Comment: Thanks! But then how can the second transformation be linear? And the matrices definitely come out coherent in that case...

Comment: @dalta Sorry for misleading you, I have edited the answer.